# gRPC response recording

Tags: java, spring, grpc

When I work with REST clients in java, I pretty much always use Wiremock to record real responses stubs, save them to files and put them in resource directory of my service tests. All clients are configured to reach out to in-memory Wiremock instance which serves recorded "real-life" stubs from resources dir.

Now, I would like to do something similar for gRPC. I use `grpc-spring-boot-starter`. I went through this page: [docu](https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/client/testing.html) and there are two ways suggested: either use mocks or create custom test service. The second option is close to what I want to achieve, but still I have to write all stubs by myself.

Does anyone know if there is something similar to Wiremock recording possible for gRPC? I have quite large payloads to work with and manually stubbing then can be problematic and error-prone. I would like to work with real data returned from real services.

Thanks!